# Truffle-Contract error with Metamask

Tags: web3js, truffle, metamask, truffle-contract

It seems that on my computer/web browser Google Chrome is slow to inject meta-mask. Therefore I have to write something like this for my App to actually get the web3 instance instead of failing:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined'){
        console.log('getting web3');
        App.web3Provider = web3.currentProvider;
    }
    else {
        console.log('No Web3 instance given!');
        // flash modal saying "please download Metamask"
    }
    web3 = new Web3(App.web3Provider);

    return App.initContract(web3);

}, 500);
```

However, this doesn't play nice with Truffle-Contract js library, which *needs* the web3 instance straight away. Does anyone have a workaround or a fix for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `truffle-contract` library doesn't need the web3 instance right away. It only needs it to be there when you start trying to use it.

```
var contract = require("truffle-contract");
var my_contract_json = require('../../../truffle/build/contracts/MyContract.json');
var MyContract;

var my_contract_deployed;

window.onload = function() {
    if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') { 
        window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);

        MyContract = contract(my_contract_json);
        MyContract.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);
        MyContract.deployed().then(function(instance) {
            my_contract_deployed = instance;
            // doWhateverUIStuff();
        });
    }
}
```

See a working example here:
https://github.com/realitykeys/realitycheck/blob/8674f7b07cef2c4c96762c30befd549138bdb8e4/assets/js/scripts/main.js#L3398

Comment: Thank you for the help! I think I was using the truffle-contract library before the web3 instance was received, as you said.